# Using ZoneDateTime.parse how would you parse the following

Tags: java, date, datetime, parsing

using ZoneDateTime.parse, how would you parse the following

> Mon Jul 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

Have to use zoneDateTime.parse is a must.

This is not for homework but for work and standards are already set.

Comment: Have you searched? What did you find? In what way was it insufficient? Have you tried anything? In what way did it fail?

Comment: Have you seen the `ZonedDateTime` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve a problem like this, first try to build a formatter that will produce the same output. Then use that for parsing.

Read the javadoc of [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to learn what formatting symbols can produce the desired output.

```
Mon                      E      day-of-week         text         Tue; Tuesday; T
Jul                      M/L    month-of-year       number/text  7; 07; Jul; July; J
01                       d      day-of-month        number       10
2019                     u      year                year         2004; 04
00                       H      hour-of-day (0-23)  number       0
:                        :      fixed text
00                       m      minute-of-hour      number       30
:                        :      fixed text
00                       s      second-of-minute    number       55
GMT                      'GMT'  fixed text
-0500                    x      zone-offset         offset-x     +0000; -08; -0830; -08:30; -083015; -08:30:15;
(                        (      fixed text
Central Daylight Time    z      time-zone name      zone-name    Pacific Standard Time; PST
)                        )      fixed text
```

Then read the fine print to learn how many of each format letter you need, e.g. that you need `dd` to get 2-digit day-of-month with leading zero.

Testing the result:

```
String expected = "Mon Jul 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)";
String format = "EEE MMM dd uuuu HH:mm:ss 'GMT'xx (zzzz)";

ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(2019, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("America/Chicago"));
System.out.println(zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format)));
System.out.println(expected);
```

*Output*

```
Mon Jul 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
Mon Jul 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

*Use it*

```
String input = "Mon Jul 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)";
String format = "EEE MMM dd uuuu HH:mm:ss 'GMT'xx (zzzz)";

ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(input, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format));
System.out.println(zdt);
```

*Output*

```
2019-07-01T00:00-05:00[America/Chicago]
```

Comment: Great answer, really well explained. I recommend specifying an English-speaking locale for the formatter.